Problemas con Callback en Dash - python
tengo la siguiente situación:
estoy diseñando un formulario interactivo en Dash, para una aplicación.
En la casilla nivel, al seleccionar un número, en la casilla Asignatura aparecen las asignaturas del nivel seleccionado, como se ve en la figura:

El código de ese callback es el siguiente:
@app.callback(
    Output('asignatura', 'options'),
    Input('nivel', 'value')
)
def actualizar_asignaturas(nivel_seleccionado):
    if nivel_seleccionado:
        asignaturas_filtradas = df_asignaturas['Asignatura'][df_asignaturas['Nivel'] == nivel_seleccionado]
        return [{'label': asignatura, 'value': asignatura} for asignatura in asignaturas_filtradas]
    return []

Después necesito recuperar la información que haya sido ingresada en las otras casillas, que se guardan en un .json.
El callback para recuperar la información es el siguiente:
@app.callback(
    [Output('nombre_unidad', 'value'),
     Output('sintesis', 'value'),
     Output('aprendizajes', 'value'),
     Output('numero_actividades', 'value'),
     Output('descripciones_actividades', 'value'),
     Output('tabla_notas', 'data')],
    [Input('nivel', 'value'),
     Input('asignatura', 'value')]
)
def cargar_informacion_notas(nivel, asignatura):   
    if nivel and asignatura:
        datos_asignatura = cargar_datos(asignatura, nivel)
        notas_data = cargar_datos(f'{asignatura}_notas', nivel)
        
        # Cargar información de la asignatura
        nombre_unidad = datos_asignatura.get('nombre_unidad', '')
        sintesis = datos_asignatura.get('sintesis', '')
        aprendizajes = datos_asignatura.get('aprendizajes', '')
        numero_actividades = datos_asignatura.get('numero_actividades', '')
        descripciones_actividades = datos_asignatura.get('descripciones_actividades', '')

        # Cargar notas de estudiantes, si existen
        data_tabla = notas_data.get('notas', [])
        
        return nombre_unidad, sintesis, aprendizajes, numero_actividades, descripciones_actividades, data_tabla
    return '', '', '', '', '', []

El problema es que cuando ejecuto el código, al escoger el nivel, no aparecen resultados en las asignaturas para elegir, como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

La verdad no tengo idea porqué está pasando eso. Debe ser que los callback se están entorpeciendo, pero no puedo encontrar el error ni menos solucionarlo.
Espero puedan darme algún consejo.
Saludos!!

no entiendo exactamente los pasos que uno toma en esta app.


Se inicia la app, el usuario selecciona un Nivel y se le aparecen las opciones de las asignatures (con el primer callback). Hasta ahora todo funciona bien, correcto?


De ahi, el usuario escoge una asignature y qué pasa? Logra seguir escogiendo valores en las otras casillas?



Gracias @AdamSchroeder por tu respuesta.
Lo que pasa es lo siguiente: escoges el nivel, la asignatura, el semestre y el informe. Con eso deberían cargarse la información guardada en las otras casillas (síntesis, aprendizajes, evaluaciones, etc). Además, carga la tabla de estudiantes con sus notas.
Puedo guardar la información y las notas, pero cuando quiero cargar esa información y esa tabla de notas, ya no aparecen las asignaturas.
Espero haya quedado claro.
Quedo atento.
Saludos!!!

Chuta, Sí es un problema medio dificil. Crees que podrías compartir todo el código de la app con el data para tratar de reproducir el problema en mi compu? Te puedo mandar mi email. Una vez vea el error reproduciéndose en mi compu, sería más facil entender donde esta el bug.
